# json:transform-from-json converts \u001e to &#30; and causing the error "Invalid XML character codepoint 30" how to handle this?

Tags: json, xml, xquery, marklogic

My JSON string has the escaped unicode  `\u001e`. Converting the JSON to XML using the function `json:transform-from-json()` converts `\u001e` to `&#30;`.

Performing `xdmp:unquote` on top of this data gives following error:

> Invalid XML character codepoint 30 at line 1 -- document contains non-XML character**

Is there a way to preserve `\u001e` as such during JSON to XML transformation using `json:transform-from-json()`?

Below is my code snippet

```
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
let $json1 := ' { "name":"John", "age":30, "text":"john\u001e" }'
let $basic := json:config("basic")
let $basicXml := json:transform-from-json($json1, $basic)
return xdmp:unquote($basicXml)
```

Answer (score 1):

The character `x1e` isn't legal in XML, even if represented as `&#x1e;` so there is no way it can be preserved as such. I don't know what the converter that you are using offers, but the `json-to-xml()` function in XPath 3.1 offers several options: retaining the JSON escape sequence `\u001e` (which has no XML-defined meaning, but may be meaningful to the application processing the document), substituting a `SUB` character, or calling a user-supplied fallback function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `xdmp:unquote` the result. `json:transform-from-json` returns the XML structure, not the string representation. By passing it into `xdmp:unquote`, you force MarkLogic to atomize the argument, resulting in a string with the illegal character as a plain character, instead of as a numeric reference.

Leaving off the `xdmp:unquote` will prevent MarkLogic from throwing an error at that stage, but you might still run into similar issues down the chain. MarkLogic does not support XPath 3.1 currently, but you could manipulate the JSON string before passing it into the transform function. Perhaps not the prettiest, but this would work:

```
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
let $json1 := ' { "name":"John", "age":30, "text":"john\u001e" }'
let $json1 := replace($json1, '(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})', '\\$1')
let $basic := json:config("basic")
let $basicXml := json:transform-from-json($json1, $basic)
return $basicXml
```

HTH!

Comment: string replace before json to xml transformation worked for me. thanks for the hep.

Comment: Hi, I would like to unescape \\u001e to \u001e in the json. however other characters like newline should stay escaped. how it can be done? TIA